# Long waiting for login prompt at screen lock. Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, login-screen, lock-screen

I have just upgraded Ubuntu 19.10 to 20.04. I hit on something that force me to wait about 20 seconds for login prompt at screen lock after I push keys. This happens every time I need to log in after screen lock.

Here, how it goes.

1) Ubuntu locks.

2) A display shuts down.

3) I move a mouse.

4) Lock screen appears. It is blurred image of desktop image.

5) I click mouse buttons all around the screen, press Enter, press all the keys on keyboard!

6) Nothing happens!

7) I have to wait about 20 seconds to see login prompt.

**ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions**

```
ls: cannot access '/home/a***v/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions': No such file or directory
```

**ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions**

```
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 мая 25  2019 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 мая 20 12:03 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 мая 20 11:45 desktop-icons@csoriano
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 мая 20 11:45 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 мая 20 11:45 ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 мая 20 12:02 workrave@workrave.org
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`.

Answer (score 1):

The cause was the fingerprint authentication daemon. My desktop computer doesn't have fingerprint hardware. So the daemon failed to start.

```
PC systemd[1]: Failed to start Fingerprint Authentication Daemon.
PC dbus-daemon[1085]: [system] Failed to activate service 'net.reactivated.Fprint': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
```

Now it works well after I had removed it by

```
sudo apt purge fprintd
```